# Where is the fixed point? -- Matlab is cluless too

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, matlab

Consider the differential equation
$$\dot{k}(t)=f(k)-(r+t_1)k-f(1-k)+(r+t_2)(1-k)$$
where $k,t_1,t_1\in[0,1]$, $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_+$. I'd like to solve for the fixed point $k_\infty$ which verifies $\dot{k}(t)=f(k_\infty)-(r+t_1)k_\infty-f(1-k_\infty)+(r+t_2)(1-k_\infty)=0$. To find an explicit solution let $f(k)=k^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in(0,1)$. I tried to solve it with matlab. The code reads

`syms k a r t1 t2 
sol = solve(k^a-(r+t1)*k-(1-k)^a+(r+t2)*(1-k) == 0, k)`

which gave `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. > In solve at 179 In Untitled2 at 2`

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this has an analytic solution for arbitrary parameters? The unknown $k$ to be solved for is being taken to an unknown arbitrary power $a$. Have you read through the documentation for `solve` and tried the various options? You indicate that your various parameters are only valid on certain domains (you omit that for $t_2$), but it looks like you're not applying any `assumptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I have no reason whatsoever to believe that an analytic solution exists. Actually I wrote up a model and tried to solve it. Since I don't know how to isolate $k$ here I thought maybe I could solve it numerically. However I am not that familiar with numerical methods and it's more like troubleshooting.
I took care of the bounds now

> `syms k a r t1 t2
>   assume(1 >= k & k >= 0)
>   assumeAlso(1 > a & a > 0)
>   assumeAlso(r > 0)
>   assumeAlso(1 >= t1 & t1 >= 0)
>   assumeAlso(1 >= t2 & t2 >= 0)
>   sol = solve(k^a-(r+t1)*k-(1-k)^a+(r+t2)*(1-k) == 0, k)`

which gives `Warning: 1 equations in 3 variables. New variables might be introduced.`
Maybe `fsolve` is more suitable?!
Since $r$, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are endogenous a universal solution like $k_\infty=g(r,t_1,t_2)$ is preferred, however I'm not certain if it actually exists.